# Filter dependencies copied by Maven's copy-dependency?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I need to essentially accomplish the following:

1. Build my library into a JAR. (Easy, already done.)
2. Copy my library's dependencies to a local folder, including the main project JAR, excluding dependencies marked as `provided`.

I can't seem to get the second part finished. Is there a better way to do this than how I'm doing it below? I'm essentially deploying these JARs to a lib directory on a server. Unfortunately, the code below includes all JARs, even `provided` ones, but doesn't include the project output JAR. Should I be using a different plugin for this?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>
    ...

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.provided</groupId>
            <artifactId>provided-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        ...

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>/hello</outputDirectory>
                            <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310539/how-to-copy-dependencies-jarswithout-test-jars-to-a-directory-using-maven

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To prevent the pluging to collect *provided* dependencies you can use @Raghuram solution (+1 for that). I tried also to skip *test* scoped dependencies and found the [issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-85) that it can not be done that simple - as *test* means '*everything*' in the plugin semantic.

So the solution to exclude *provided* and *test* scope is to includeScope *runtime*.

```
<includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
```

After collecting the dependencies you can copy the projects jar with the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to the target directory, e.g.:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${java.io.tmpdir}/test</outputDirectory>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>                        
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                        <copy
                            file="${build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"
                            todir="${java.io.tmpdir}/test" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I do not know any other solution - beside creating a new *pom-dist.xml* (maybe `<packaging>pom</packaging>`) which just holds the dependency to your library and collects all transitive dependencies exclusive test/provided scope. You can *execute* this with `mvn -f pom-dist.xml package` if you do not want to provide a whole new project.

Answer (score 9):

As documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#excludeScope), you could try setting `excludeScope` parameter to exclude dependants with `provided` scope.

```
<excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
```

As for the plugin excluding the current project jar, I guess this is by design.
You could create a separate maven project to do this job.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my two cents.

Putting the `<excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>` in the execution didn't work.

To exclude the provided jars put the element outside of the execution:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Command: `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`.

Jars are copied to `target/dependency`.