# How to copy dependencies jars (without test jars) to a directory using maven?

Tags: maven

I see `maven-dependency-plugin` does this; however, it seems to copy everything (including test jars) to the destination directory. Anyone know how to configure this plugin to exclude test jars?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is not clear if you wanted to exclude jars with `test` *scope* or test related jars (`test` *classifier*).  In either case, there are two properties of [dependency:copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) which can help you.

- [excludeClassifiers](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#excludeClassifiers) Comma Separated list of Classifiers to exclude. Empty String indicates don't exclude anything (default).
- [excludeScope](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#excludeScope)     Scope to exclude. An Empty string indicates no scopes (default).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i use <includeScope>compile</includeScope> and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Raghuram Mike here did raise a point, one cannot exclude scope test. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850788/filter-dependencies-copied-by-mavens-copy-dependency

Comment: I am using `<excludeScope>` for provided, transitive dependencies don't get copied for the default scope, even though `<excludeTransitive>` is false

Answer (score 41):

Mike answered their own question in a comment above. I think Mike's use case is similar to mine where I want to copy all of the jars I depend upon as well as my own jar in order to create a directory hierarchy sufficient to execute the program without including those dependencies directly into my own jar.

The answer to achieve this is:

```
<includeScope>compile</includeScope>
```

This directive goes into the  section of the pom.xml for the maven-dependency plugin. For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

excludeScope won't work because excluding test aborts the build and excludes all possible scopes. Instead the included scope needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Using `<includeScope>runtime</includeScope>` may be better yet, as it copies compile and runtime dependencies. For instance, if you use SLF4J logging, then the `slf4j-api` would be a compile time dependency, whereas the bridges (`jcl-over-slf4j`, `jul-to-slf4j`) and the backend (e.g. `slf4j-log4j12`) would be runtime dependencies.

Comment: Just a note that you can pass this on the command-line too (just like excludeScope):  `mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies -DincludeScope=runtime`

Answer (score 11):

Documentation says: The scopes being interpreted are the scopes as
Maven sees them, not as specified in the pom.

```
In summary:
  * runtime scope gives runtime and compile dependencies
  * compile scope gives compile, provided, and system dependencies
  * test (default) scope gives all dependencies
  * provided scope just gives provided dependencies
  * system scope just gives system dependencies
```

According to my experience, if you just wanna run your classes with compile scoped dependencies, specified in project pom.xml file, you must add `-DincludeScope=runtime` java system setting, like so:

```sh
mvn compile dependency:copy-dependencies -DincludeScope=runtime
java -cp "target/dependecy/*:target/classes" com.example.Main args...
```

---

Regards